# Why Java doesn't implement MRO like Python

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

As far as I know Java doesn't support multiple inheritance to safeguard from the diamond problem, ambiguity and maybe a few other reasons as well. But I see that Python handles the same problem with [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). Why doesn't Java incorporate something similar to support multiple inheritance?

Comment: Because it's a different language, with different needs, and different design goals. Please take the [tour] and understand that StackOverflow is not a discussion and/or gripe forum.

Comment: I was trying to understand is there any strong reason java still doesn't want to support multiple inheritance

Comment: I guess the "strong reason" is that it has no reason to 

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. Maybe Java guru knows the real reason, but  my guess is supporting multiple inheritance is not always better than not supporting it, and Java's concept seems to be simple than language such as C++, so maybe they did't want feature that is often confused to the users.